# Aggregating metrics at parent

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, outliers, aggregation

I have a model with several independent variables/metrics that each additionally has a corresponding unit, pre-defined upper/lower bounds and a desired value.

Now I wish to compute some basic descriptive staitistics (mode, median, mean, range(abs(max-min)), IQR, stddev, relative stddev) for each variable indicating how "faulty" (outliers) that variable is. Since each variable has a different unit it should be independent of the unit to be able to aggregate in the second step.

Finally, I want to aggregate those metrics at a parent variable telling me how "faulty" this parent variable, or more specifically its children are.

How can I detect outliers at the child variables, compare range with std dev? I was thinking about using the grand mean and the coefficient of variation at the parent variable. However, is there some other better way (or 'proper') way of doing this? If I were to do this, would it make statistical sense?

Something like that ([Aggregating risk scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163921/aggregating-risk-scores)) would be maybe a good fit for aggregating the relative standard deviations from the children variables?